# sending data to mySQL database

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm trying to send data to my database, when my register button is clicked without filling any field on the registration form it displays the "field empty" message but when I fill it and click the register button nothing happens.
This is the code that is supposed to send the data

```
btn_signup.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button btn_signup = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
    btn_signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            registerUser();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.tv_login:
            break;

    }

}


private void registerUser() {

    String name = et_name.getText().toString();
    String email = et_email.getText().toString();
    String password = et_password.getText().toString();

    if (!name.isEmpty() && !email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {


    } else {

        Snackbar.make(getView(), "Fields are empty !", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();
```

I defined my URL_REGISTER in my AppConfig.java like this

```
public class AppConfig {

public static String URL_LOGIN = "http://192.168.43.142/android_login_api/login.php";


public static String URL_REGISTER = "http://192.168.43.142/android_login_api/register.php";
}
```

Comment: Where is the async task which is supposed to be hitting the login endpoint?

Comment: @Tim It's Volley...  `StringRequest`

Answer (score 1):

Your Block is empty!!

```
if (!name.isEmpty() && !email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
  // you have to do something here to get some output
  }
```

Comment: Regardless of that being empty, the StringRequest would still be created

Comment: No, I can see that request is outside of the method.@cricket_007

Comment: Well, yes, probably a typo with the brackets

Comment: i have added this line "registerUser(name, email, password);" but still nothing happens on button click

Comment: As i said in my answer. You have to make your string request inside the if condition.